# "Neural Networks Learn in Continuous space" - What does this statement mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, neural-networks

I was reading the paper on "Recurrent neural network based language model" by Tomas Mikolov et. al and I came across this statement "Neural Networks Learn in Continuous space". Please help me in understanding the meaning of continuous space here and how neural network learns in the same. In other words what does this statement mean?

Comment: I think they may be referring to the fact that parameters of neurons in most neural network models are not integers, but floating point numbers (or, I guess, fixed-point decimals). Floating point numbers are still discrete, but for many purposes they behave continuously.

Comment: For example, the threshold for a neuron firing may be $1.92\ldots$, and slowly raise to $2.40\ldots$ during training. The authors may just be pointing out that this change is allowed to be gradual by the model.

Comment: I think you should either directly ask the authors or give a bit more context: "Note that such modification
is very similar to cache techniques for backoff models, with the
difference that neural networks learn in continuous space, so if
’dog’ and ’cat’ are related, frequent occurrence of ’dog’ in testing
data will also trigger increased probability of ’cat’."